# Soap get arguments with wrong order in twisted

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, soappy

Now i use twisted.soap to build my soap server, I'd like to build a function with plural arguments like this:

```
def soap_searchFlight(self,name=None,startpoint=None,destination=None):
    d=Deferred()
    d.addCallback(functions.searchFlight)
    d.addErrback(functions.failure)
    print "name"+name
    print "startpoint"+startpoint
    print "destination"+destination
    requestdic={"name":name,"startpoint":startpoint,"destination":destination}
    print requestdic
    d.callback(requestdic)
    return d.result
```

and I wrote a script to test :

```
    import SOAPpy
    import twisted
    p = SOAPpy.SOAPProxy('http://localhost:7080/')
    p.config.dumpSOAPOut=1
    p.config.dumpSOAPIn=1
    print p.searchFlight(name='3548',startpoint="北京飞机场",destination="上海飞机场")
```

It gives me back like this:

```
name上海飞机场
startpoint北京飞机场
destination3548
```

it looks like the args order are totally wrong so what happens and how can i ensure the right order ?

Comment: But if i call the method like this way it works fine:p.searchFlight('3548',"北京飞机场","上海飞机场")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing `functions.searchFlight`, it's a little hard to tell, but it appears that you're passing a dict to in in a callback, then *assuming* that the items in the dict are in a particular order (they're not).

Change the signature of `functions.searchFlight` to take a tuple, and call it with a tuple in the order you want.  (or pass in an ordered dict...or don't assume the dict's items are in the order that you created it in).